# Estimating Coding/Development efforts?

Tags: project

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How possible is it to estimate time for programming projects?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39468/how-possible-is-it-to-estimate-time-for-programming-projects)

We have designed a User Interface (UI) in HTML for an Intranet Application.it took almost 30 days to make it,how we should estimate the development effort(coding) for it,is there some ratio we can use to estimate,it need not have to be exact but some estimate would help.

Answer (score 3):

There is no really easy way to make an estimate like this without significantly more information.

Development could be very fast if the backing code is the same for the majority of the pages you wrote, or extremely slow if every page requires its own code with complex logic.

Estimating is pretty tricky, it relies on a programmer to judge based on their experience with similar problems and based on a solid understanding of the tasks required to complete the project. Since we don't know the tasks required to complete we can't offer an estimate.

These three questions may offer some insight into the estimation process:

[How possible is it to estimate time for programming projects?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39468/how-possible-is-it-to-estimate-time-for-programming-projects)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423508/calculating-project-programming-times

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971905/estimating-time-to-complete-a-programming-task

Answer (score 1):

## Sorry

Estimation of coding effort is based on...**coding effort**. How long it took you to build the HTML front-end is irrelevant. There's no way around actually breaking the functionality down into tasks, estimating each task, and adding up the results. Then applying adjustements as you see fit to account for difficulty, scheduling issues, testing time, whatever.

There are a number of ways to estimate software projects; all of them actually require you to define the tasks involved.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to ask the ones who are to make it.

They usually need to do a bit of it to see if there is anything unexpected somewhere, and then they should be able to give an estimate.

Time is frequently spent in strange places.